# Excel VBA - "Autofill Method of Range Class Failed" on macro

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I have an issue on a VBA code that was written by somebody else but that I need to fix.

On the following code, I get the "Autofill Method of Range Class Failed" error and I don't really understand why, especially since a month ago, this same code was running without this error appearing.

```
Dim lastrow2 As Double
lastrow2 = tab2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

Range("D2").FormulaArray = _
     "=INDEX(label,MATCH(1,(user=RC[-3])*(LEFT(role,5)=""SA.AM""),0))"
Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lastrow2)

Dim i As Integer
For i = lastrow2 To 2 Step -1
     If IsError(Cells(i, 4)) = False Then Rows(i).Delete
     Next i
        
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

This error pops on the `Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lastrow2)` line code.

Does anyone know why please? Thank you in advance

I've tried to see the other posts on this error but none was the right solution.

Comment: `lastrow2 ` would be better as `Long` or `Integer`

Comment: Use the debugger to check the value of lastrow2 - that method of finding it doesn't work if there are gaps in the data

Comment: Replace *Double* and *Integer* with *Long*. Then qualify all the ranges i.e. `tab2.Range(...)`, `tab2.Cells(...)`, `tab2.Rows(...)` (`tab2.Columns(...)`).

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I tried to replace by Long but still got the same issue.

Also, how can I see lastrow2's value please? Is there print methods like in other languages?

@VBasic2008 what do you mean by qualifying the ranges please?

Comment: Oh I understood what you meant by qualify. I will add "tab2" before each method and try